# Why is my webapp only serving the css file when running as iis express?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

So I have this web app which runs just fine when I debug it using IIS Express, it's using the correct css files and what not.

But if I try running it as the project exe, it doesnt seem to find this path

```
<link href="~/assets/css/dark_theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And I'n my startup.cs I'm using

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

When i run the executable inside

```
bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1
```

Do I then need to change this path `href="~/assets/css/dark_theme.css"` to something else?

Comment: Try without `~`

Comment: Still the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Update this:

```
<link href="~/assets/css/dark_theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

to

```
<link href="./assets/css/dark_theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
```